# UIStatusbar changes orientation, but everything else stays the same

Tags: iphone, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a tabbar app, with some uinavigationcontrollers.

In every VC i have:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

But for some reason when rotating the screen the status bar rotates, but the rest of my view stays the same. How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this to your info.plist [image]

Comment: Nop, still have the same problem

Answer (score -1):

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` would normally be implemented like this (for an iPhone app that supports rotation):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

It's not clear from your question whether you want the subviews to rotate or the status bar to not rotate.

Comment: I've just implemented a test project and this works perfectly. You've got something else wrong. Go back to first principles, create an empty project and gradually add similar views & VCs until you can reproduce the problem. It's difficult to diagnose this issue without more info.